# Selecting value from Pandas without going through .values[0]

Tags: python, pandas, series

An example dataset I'm working with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"competitorname": ["3 Musketeers", "Almond Joy"], "winpercent": [67.602936, 50.347546] }, index = [1, 2])
```

I am trying to see whether `3 Musketeers` or `Almond Joy` has a higher `winpercent`. The code I wrote is:

```
more_popular = '3 Musketeers' if df.loc[df["competitorname"] == '3 Musketeers', 'winpercent'].values[0] > df.loc[df["competitorname"] == 'Almond Joy', 'winpercent'].values[0] else 'Almond Joy'
```

My question is

Can I select the values I am interested in without python returning a Series? Is there a way to just do

```
df[df["competitorname"] == 'Almond Joy', 'winpercent']
```

and then it would return a simple

```
50.347546
```

?

I know this doesn't make my code significantly shorter but I feel like I am missing something about getting values from pandas that would help me avoid constantly adding

```
.values[0]
```

Comment: Regarding your example boolean mask, you just need an extra set of brackets: `df[df["competitorname"] == 'Almond Joy']['winpercent']` but that still returns a series. `.loc[]` or `.iloc[]` can work as well as `.values` for accessing the values of a given frame or series, but most built-in methods return dataframes or series intentionally, to avoid data going into and out of pandas, under the assumption that there will be further data processing downstream unless you explicitly access the values by themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue is that there *could* be multiple matches, so we will always need to extract the match(es) at some point in the pipeline:

- ##### Use [`Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) on the boolean mask

  Since `False` is 0 and `True` is 1, using [`Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) on the boolean mask will give you the index of the first `True`:

  ```
  df.loc[df['competitorname'].eq('Almond Joy').idxmax(), 'winpercent']
  # 50.347546
  ```

  This assumes there is at least 1 `True` match, otherwise it will return the first `False`.
- ##### Or use [`Series.item`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.htm) on the result

  This is basically just an alias for `Series.values[0]`:

  ```
  df.loc[df['competitorname'].eq('Almond Joy'), 'winpercent'].item()
  # 50.347546
  ```

  This assumes there is exactly 1 `True` match, otherwise it will throw a ValueError.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply sorting the dataframe by "winpercent" and then taking the top row?

```python
df.sort_values(by="winpercent", ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

then to see the winner's row

```python
df.head(1)
```

or to get the values

```python
df.iloc[0]["winpercent"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the returned Series has a single element, you can simply use `.item()` to get it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "competitorname": ["3 Musketeers", "Almond Joy"], 
    "winpercent": [67.602936, 50.347546]
}, index = [1, 2])

s = df.loc[df["competitorname"] == 'Almond Joy', 'winpercent']  # a pandas Series
print(s)
# output
# 2    50.347546
# Name: winpercent, dtype: float64

v = df.loc[df["competitorname"] == 'Almond Joy', 'winpercent'].item()  # a scalar value
print(v)
# output
# 50.347546
```